# Number theoretical proof for equality between $a^{m*\varphi(x)}$ mod $x$ for different $m$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$a^{\varphi(x)} \equiv a^{m.\varphi(x)}$ mod $\;x$   for all $m>0$

Is this assumption correct? Is so, prove correctness. How can I prove this?

Comment: I think $\varphi{(6)} = 2$ and $2^2=4 (mod\; 6)$ and $2^4=4 (mod\; 6)$ so, what you tried to comment, either I didn't understand, or wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We first show this for prime powers:

If $p \nmid a$ then $(a, p^k)=1$ so we have by [Euler's totient theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) that $$a^{\varphi(p^k)} \equiv 1 \pmod{p^k}$$

Thus

$$a^{\varphi(p^k)} \equiv 1 \equiv a^{m \varphi(p^k)} \pmod{p^k}$$

If $p \mid a$, then $\varphi(p^k)=p^{k-1}(p-1) \geq 2^{k-1} \geq k$ so $p^k \mid a^{\varphi(p^k)}$. Thus

$$a^{\varphi(p^k)} \equiv 0 \equiv a^{m \varphi(p^k)} \pmod{p^k}$$

Therefore in any case, we have for $m>0$

$$a^{\varphi(p^k)} \equiv a^{m \varphi(p^k)} \pmod{p^k}$$

---

Back to the general case. Write $x=p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2} \ldots p_l^{k_l}$. Then for each $i$ we have

$$a^{\varphi(x)} \equiv a^{\varphi \left(\dfrac{x}{p_i^{k_i}}\right)\times \varphi(p_i^{k_i})} \equiv a^{\varphi(p_i^{k_i})} \equiv a^{m\varphi \left(\dfrac{x}{p_i^{k_i}}\right)\times \varphi(p_i^{k_i})} \equiv a^{m\varphi(x)} \pmod{p_i^{k_i}}$$

Combining gives

$$a^{\varphi(x)} \equiv a^{m\varphi(x)} \pmod{x}$$